Thumb rules for heat dissipation to ambient air (convection)
If I have a component (linear voltage regulator or a power mosfet for example) mounted on a flat plate of aluminium (it being used as a heat sink), how do I go about estimating steady state temperature values of the aluminium plate. Are there any thumb rules for such estimations?
Example parameters: (very close to a project I will be working on)
Power dissipation in the component = 10 watts.
Ambient air temperature = 40 degree C (max)
Aluminium metal plate dimensions = 15 cm X 15 cm flat plate of 2 mm thickness (without fins). Assume the contact area between component and plate to be 5 cm X 5 cm as shown below:

Only one side of plate (non-component side) is exposed to open air. Component side is inside the enclosure. This flat plate is the only metal part. Other 5 sides of the enclosure will be plastic. So heat transfer to the air will effectively happen from a 15 cm X 15 cm area.
Wind flow = None. Only convection air current
The temperature of the metal plate needs to be 65 degree C or less. I need a way to approximate this thing using some thumb rules. I am thinking of a crude equation involving wattage (heat dissipation), surface area and ambient temperature. I tried looking for convection heat transfer equations but couldn't find complete details. For example:
Convection formula is given as:

Q = 10 watts
A = 0.0225 sq m
Delta T = 25 K
However I am not sure what value of h should I take.

Will the plate be mounted horizontal or vertical, as that affects the convection heat transfer?

@CarlRutschow - not decided yet. Which orientation is better for convection? Horizontal will be an easier design decision. But if there are good benefits, vertical mount can be planned as well. Would like to understand the differences between the two to make the right decision.

I could understand that vertical surface will have better convection. However I'd still like to understand how much better will it be as compared to a horizontal one. This will help me make the right tradeoff between size and design of the enclosure.
